# Regex to extract only String from a matched content using lookahead and lookbehind

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

Consider the following text which is part of a file

> Name & Emp No 
>  Jack Doe 1234  
>  John 12345 
>  Dob :
>   28/12/1987

Now i would like to write a single regex (**java flavor**) to extract only the names from the above text.

I tried the following regex with lookahead and lookbehind

```
(?<=(Name\s&\sEmp\sNo)\s{2,3})((.{1,100}\s{0,3}){0,5}?)(?=Dob)
```

and the output which i got was

```
Jack Doe 1234[CR][LF]John 12345[CR][LF]
```

If i want only the names as output, how can i modify this regex?

Comment: your formatting makes unclear for me. is there any newline exists in your input?

Comment: This is how it is. (Name & Emp No\r\n
Jack Doe 1234\r\n
John 12345\r\n
Dob : 28/12/1987\r\n)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an attempt based on the assumption that the names are present at the start of a line, and followed by digits:

```
String test = 
    "Name & Emp No\r\n" +
    "Jack Doe 1234\r\n" + 
    "John 12345\r\n" +
    "Dob : 28/12/1987";
//                           | start of line
//                           | | alphabetics and whitespace
//                           | |             | greedy quantifier
//                           | |             | | lookahead for digits
//                           | |             | |        | multi line pattern
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[\\p{Alpha}\\s]+(?=\\d)", Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

**Output**

```
Jack Doe 
John
```

**Note**

- The trick here is that neither `"Name "` nor `"Dob "` will be matched
  because they are not followed by digits.
- The names that **are** matched have a single space at the end (you can sanitize with `String.trim()`)

Comment: What about names like: `O'Brian` or `Jean-Pierre`?

Comment: @M42 if that is indeed a requirement, it isn't present in the question. But yes, you raise a valid point.

Comment: Sure, but I guess `Jack Doe` and `John`  aren't the only names OP wants to catch.

Comment: @M42 again, you have a point but it is up to OP to specify the correct requirements. Double-guessing doesn't make much sense and might be even counter-productive.

Comment: @Mena I wanna extract the text between "Name & Emp No" & "DOB". This is just a small part of a very big file. I should have mentioned it. My bad!

Comment: @M42 Let's just assume that I need to extract only the alphabets.

Comment: @HariNarayanan so... **all** the text? i.e. `"Jack Doe 1234\r\nJohn 12345"`?

Comment: @Mena Only the alphabets `Jack Doe John` The regex which i have mentioned in the question already extracts the text which you have mentioned. I wanted to know whether its possible to extract only the Alphabets.

Answer (score 0):

This regex should help you.

```
^([[:alpha:]]+[ ]?)+(?=[ ]+\d+)
```

[Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/hI7nL6/2)

Comment: Java doesn't support the POSIX character-class syntax; instead of `[[:alpha:]]+`, you would use `\p{Alpha}+`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-line solution:

```
String[] names = str.replaceAll("(?s).*No\\s+|\\s+Dob.*", "").split("\\s+\\d+\\s*");
```

This strips off the leading and trailing rubbish, then splits of whitespace-then-digits-then-optional-whitespace.

Some key point here:

- the use of the DOTALL flag `(?s)`, which makes dot match newlines
- whitespace `\s` matches newlines
- java's `split()` discards trailing blank elements by default (that's why there's no need to handle the trailing digits after the last name.
- this works with any number of "name then digits" lines between the header and footer

---

Some test code:

```
String str = "Lots of lines\r\nName & Emp No\r\nJack Doe 1234\r\nJohn 12345\r\nDob : 28/12/1987\r\nLots more lines";
String[] names = str.replaceAll("(?s).*No\\s+|\\s+Dob.*", "").split("\\s+\\d+\\s*");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(names));
```

Output:

```
[Jack Doe, John]
```